# Ethernet disabled when Modem connects to internet

Tags: ethernet

I am able to access my modem via ethernet when it's not connected to the internet. When I plug the cable connection and and the modem connects to the internet, the ethernet connection disables and on my computer it will say "unplugged".

I am able to connect to the internet via WiFi but not by ethernet, and not even able to access my router at all via ethernet, but it works just fine via WiFi. Is there anything I can do, does any of this make sense?

My modem is a Ubee, 3 in 1 modem/router/phone.

Comment: Sadly, home networking questions are off topic here.

Comment: 5 years later and I ran into this today. I LOVE 2020!

Answer (score 0):

first of all check the bios to see that no one turned the Ethernet port off.

Comment: And how would you access a cable modem's BIOS?

Comment: I think he mean the BIOS of the PC not the router

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:

- Be sure your Ethernet cable work on other PC.
- Try other Ethernet port.
- Be sure your Ethernet card work and have right driver installed.
- Press start button and "R" then run CMD.
- Ping your router IP address and see if that's work.
- Be sure your IPs on your PC not static over Ethernet.
- Be sure your DHCP service ON at both Wireless/Ethernet.
- If that's still not work with you, force you PC to have static IP address "give it a try"
- If all of these still not work, make "hard reset" to your router.

**NOTE** Some routers have option to disable/enable Ethernet port check that too.

**NOTE2** Some PCs Ethernet card will not work perfectly if you are enabling both cards Ethernet and wireless for no reason, try to disable the wireless and check if that's work.

- if nothing work then uninstall your Ethernet driver and setup it
  again.
- If that's still not work try to connect other PC to your router via Ethernet, if that PC work then hmm I don't know..